# Invoke procmail on spool file using new .procmailrc?

Tags: rhel, email, postfix, procmail

I've recently configured new `.procmailrc` and `.forward` files to work with our Postfix mail server.  I've tested it with new Emails, and the new `.procmailrc` is properly filtering and forwarding as desired.

Now I would like to somehow re-process the entire contents of my `/var/spool/mail/***username***` file using the new `.procmailrc` so that all 2000+ messages will be properly sorted into my new `~/mail/Likely-Spam`, `~/mail/Almost-Certainly-Spam`, `~/mail/Cron-Jobs`, `~/mail/Email-Backup`, etc..., and forward all non-filtered messages to my company outlook account... for posterity.

Is there a straightforward command to accomplish this?

My mail server is running RHEL 7 with postfix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`procmail` comes with another program called `formail` which can be used to process an existing mbox.  You can use that to pipe your mailbox back into `procmail`.

To avoid race-conditions with newly arriving mail, I'd rename the spool mbox before processing it.  For example:

```
mv /var/spool/mail/username /var/spool/mail/username.orig
formail -s procmail < /var/spool/mail/username.orig
rm /var/spool/mail/username.orig
```

any arguments and options after `-s procmail` will be passed on to procmail.

From the `formail` man page:

> `-s`
>
> The input will be split up into separate mail messages, and piped
>   into  a  program  one  by  one (a new program is started for every
>   part).
>
> `-s` has to be the last option specified, the **first** argument
>   following  it  is  expected to be the name of a program, **any other**
>   **arguments will be passed along to it**.
>
> If you  omit  the  program,
>   then `formail` will  simply  concatenate the split mails on stdout
>   again.

see `man formail` and `man procmail` for more details.

Comment: Thank you cas.  I was forced to stay home from work today to care for my wife.  I'll work on this, and let you know soon.